# How can i modify sortable textboxes while also being able to add text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 varients in my code.

I have a table that i add `sortable()` to and if you swap the comments, it adds to it `sortable({cancel:"th"});`

I was curious how to do this?  How would i make it so if i click the textbox has focus, but if i drag it will start the sorting procedure.

http://jsfiddle.net/8RtzL/

Right now, if i do 1 way, it wont let me focus to add text, and if i do it the other way, it does not make it easy to grab to sort the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8RtzL/2/

You need to cancel the inputs as well. I would give the table elements some padding and background color, or look into a [draggable handle element](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle).

```
$("table.title > tbody").sortable({cancel:"input, th"});
```

Comment: Do i NEED to do it this way?  I mean, i was hoping to not need the handle... If this is the case, I will just had a handle of sorts